# How to accomplish full text search in MySQL 5.5 Engine = innodb?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I've gone through many articles but didn't find how can I do it alternate to match and against. In one of my project I need to use this and it is not suitable to upgrade the version of the database.

Is there any way?

Comment: Any examples of what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: My table contains columns like fname, lname, about. If user searches for "Abcd Efg" then results need to be fetched.

Comment: You can't do it. In 5.5, full-text search is only available with MyISAM.

Comment: You can use `LIKE` for simple pattern matching. But it will be inefficient if you have `%` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: There are performance issues with like @Barmar

Comment: I know, I said that in my comment.